# Replace a number behind word in a text file

Tags: python, string, text

I seem to be a bit confused about how to use strings, int, and floats.
Im trying to read a .txt file name TEST.txt.
This contains:

```
Hoi

Total: 350
```

I want to add a value to the total number.
I am trying this like so:

```
# open the file
with open("TEST.txt") as f:
    # read lines
    lines = f.readlines()
# set a sting only to read line 2
string = (lines[2])
# remove the characters from the string
stringNub = string.replace("Total: ","")
print (stringNub)

min = 300
sum3 = int(stringNub) + int(min)
print(sum3)

# replace the string
with open('TEST.txt','r') as file:
    filedata = file.read()
    filedata = filedata.replace(stringNub,sum3)
with open('TEST.txt','w') as file:
    file.write(filedata)

    # replace the string
    with open('TEST.txt','r') as file:
        filedata = file.read()
        filedata = filedata.replace(string2,sum3)
    with open('TEST.txt','w') as file:
        file.write(filedata)
```

I was hoping that the code would write to the txt like so:

```
Hoi

Total: 650
```

Instead I ended up with this error:
TypeError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not int

But if I make my **int** a **str** the output will be **350300**.

(I'm very much a beginner / hobbyist).
I know the code probably doesn't look that pretty, but can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `filedata.replace(stringNub, str(sum3))`. Convert to string just before replacement. No need for `int(min)` as `min` is already an int. Also avoid using keywords and stdlib functions as variable name.

Comment: The error you get is pretty expressive. It says argument 2 must be str - pretty straightforward.

Comment: @Ashwani Thats it! Thank you.

Comment: @Austin  I know it's straightforward, I'm still missing some of the basics, but this helped :)

Comment: @Ashwani The script does work with _filedata.replace(stringNub, str(sum3))_
But for some reason it removes 1 **\n** if there was any behind it.
Any clue why this is happening ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution. Replace the number rewriting it in the correct file position.

```
with open('TEST.txt', 'r+') as f:
    text = f.read()
    i = text.index('Total: ') + 7
    num = int(text[i:]) + 300
    f.seek(i)
    f.write(str(num))
```

Comment: That looks a lot nicer! I tried the code and it works, except I end up with Total303 Instead of Total: 303

Comment: @myosis Really? I tested it with the original content of the file and it worked...

Comment: It’s probably me, I would like to use it this way though. Using it as a straight copy, but with a different result. I'm using python 3.8.1